# Question about matrix exponential

Tags: matrices

I am doing a question in differential geometry and want to see is the following true:

Let $A \in \mathbb{M}_n$, is $e^{\text{tr}(A)}=\text{tr}(e^A)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential

Answer (score 5):

The formula is $$\det e^A=e^{\text{tr}\, a}$$See [here, theorem 3.10](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0005032v1.pdf)

Comment: I found $\det e^A=e^{\text{tr}\, A}$ already in the question, and now want to find the derivative of it at some point say $A$. And in Lee's book, it said: $D \det_A(B) = \det (A) \text{tr} (A^{-1} B)$, I just want to know how he get this.

Comment: What's the reference you're using? Lee's Smooth Manifolds?

Comment: Yes, 2nd ed. pg. 196

Answer (score 5):

Let $I$ be the $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}2\times 2$ identity matrix. Then $e^{\tr A} = e^2$, but $\tr e^A = 2e$.

Comment: This is a good counterexample. Maybe even better than quoting the actual result.